# set label text equal to array value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

In the myProj.h file I have declared:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *wordsArray;
```

in the .m file I use the following to add some values in viewDidLoad:

```
[_wordsArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party."]];
[_wordsArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Four score and seven years ago our forefathers..."]];
[_wordsArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"A coward dies many deaths; a brave man but one."]];
```

I also set a counter here (defined as an int in the .h file):

```
__cntr = 0;
```

In the (IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender   I want to change the label (*somelabel) text to the next value in the array [0] (then iterate _cntr to 1 and get that value, etc). So I 
have:

```
_somelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_wordsArray objectAtIndex:__cntr]];
```

Builds but when I run and press the button the label text turns to (Null).

So is the problem with the addition of the values to the array or pulling them out. Thanks

Comment: Why do you have a public property for `wordsArray`? Do other classes set the array or get values from it? If not, it shouldn't be a public property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you haven't initialized your mutable array.  In viewDidLoad add:

```
_wordsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

before adding any objects to it.